# best method to update the SQL table data from c# .NET 2005

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, dataset

I have a dataset with some 30 records in it. I want to update it to the database tables. which is the best method to update the table. 
          I am unable to use dataadapter.update() since i am using a procedure to populate the dataset.
        is there any efficient way to update other than iterating through EACH record and updating it

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx) for how to work with xml datatype introduced in SQL Server 2005. Within an SP you can use UPDATE FROM statement. The source for the update will be a select from xml-parameter you pass into the SP. You can do the same in SQL Server 2000 but that requires a few more lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you think of calling a stored-procedure...and passing your records as XML type input parameter?

Comment: yes i thought to do that but is there any other way to do ? If there is no other option i would do that only.Can you please give me some sample to do that .